# Отмена disabled по таймеру у кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

На многих форумах видел таймер встроенный в кнопку, и пока время (отображающееся на таймере) не пройдет, кнопка находится в состоянии disabled. Буду благодарен за пример или рабочий скрипт. (гогл не помог)

Comment: что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: google driven development?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var but = $(this);
    var time = 30; //задаем время в течении которого кнопка будет не активна
    var timeInterval = setInterval(function() {

      if (time <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
      }
      if (time == 0) {
        $(but).children('span').html("");
        $(but).prop("disabled", false);
      } else {
        $(but).children('span').html(time);
        $(but).prop("disabled", true);
      }
      time = time - 1;
    }, 1000);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>knopka <span></span>
</button>

<button>knopka <span></span>
</button>

<button>knopka <span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: И тем не менее, хотя вы видите что топикстартер не хочет и пальцем об палец ударить ("сделайте всё за меня") вы всё же решили ответить. Причём, ответ - чистый код, без всяких объяснений, почему так. Лучше не гонитесь за репой в следующий раз.

Comment: @A K мнение других пользователей может не совпадать с вашим. Если бы автор вопроса "ударил пальцем об палец", вопроса не возникло бы вообще. Вы можете отдать свой голос против вопроса или ответа, если они вам не нравится. Или проголосовать за закрытие вопроса, если считаете, что он не надлежащего качества или нарушает правила SO.

Comment: @ A K согласен с вами что автор вопроса и палец об палец не ударил для решения задачи. Мне просто стало интересно смогу ли я решить данную задачу и раз код уже написан то почему его не опубликовать. В части объяснений если автор все же захочет разобраться то можно и документацию почитать ну или тут в комментариях спросить.